# What happened to Voldemort's body after his death?

Tags: harry-potter

I mean, after his true death; after the duel with Harry at Hogwarts.  Perhaps Order of Phoenix members did something with it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> They moved Voldemort’s body and laid it in a chamber off the [Great] Hall[.]
>   <sub>*Deathly Hallows* - page 596 - Bloomsbury - chapter 36, *The Flaw In the Plan*</sub>

I kind of don't think that people were exactly lined up to claim Voldemort's body. After the above quote, there is no further canon reference to the disposal of Voldemort's body or how that may have occurred in any of the ten canon books or any interview with J.K. Rowling I've ever read.

Comment: I think a reasonable inference would be that it was cremated or otherwise magically destroyed. I don't think anyone would see a purpose or have the desire to bury him, and the Ministry would probably want to avoid a shrine forming around it, or some attempt to use it to restore life to him if it became possible to do so.